# ¿porque cuando hago click en el svg de completado 2 veces el primer elemento queda con el id completed?

Tags: javascript

Cuando hago click en el svg de la check mark me pasa a id completed y si lo vuelvo a clickear me pasa a id todo, eso funciona bien pero el problema es que al regresar al id todo el primer elemento del array queda con id completed y no deberia ser asi.

aqui la foto del primer click al li que dice "walk the dog"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui la foto del segundo click al li que dice "walk the dog", como pueden ver el elemento "Hello world!" queda con id completed sin haberlo clickeado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function renderTodoList() {
  if (!data.todo.length && !data.completed.length) return;

  for (let i = 0; i < data.todo.length; i++) {
    const value = data.todo[i];
    addItemToDOM(value);
  }

  for (let j = 0; j < data.completed.length; j++) {
    const value = data.completed[j];
    addItemToDOM(value, true);
  }
}

function dataObjectUpdated() {
  localStorage.setItem("todoList", JSON.stringify(data));
}


function completeItem() {
  const item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  const parent = item.parentNode;
  const id = parent.id;
  const value = item.innerText;

  if (id === "todo") {
    data.todo.splice(data.todo.indexOf(value), 1);
    data.completed.push(value);
  } else {
    data.completed.splice(data.todo.indexOf(value), 1);
    data.todo.push(value);
  }

  dataObjectUpdated();

  const target =
    id === "todo"
      ? document.getElementById("completed")
      : document.getElementById("todo");

  parent.removeChild(item);
  target.insertBefore(item, target.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debia remover el estado hover en los dispositivos moviles

```css
ul.todo:not(#completed) li .buttons button.complete:hover svg {
  background-color: rgba(37, 185, 154, 0.75);
}

ul.todo:not(#completed) li .buttons button.complete:hover svg .fill {
  fill: #fff;
}
```